# Selenium plugin for mobile app testing OR any other better & suitable tools for mobile app testing

Tags: android, ios, plugins, selenium, automated-tests

Is there any plugin for Selenium to run automated tests for an (own) app on mobile devices (for the OS iOS, Android and Windows)?

I have searched for 2 hours but the information I found is quite confusing in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use [robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/).

There is also another tool called [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) which has a different approach.

Comment: Is there recording and playing back facilities on robotium?

Answer (score 2):

You can go with **MonkeyTalk**. It provides support for both iPhone and Android. There is also an IDE called **MonkeyTalk IDE** which is capable of recording and playing back your test cases using either a device or an emulator or simulator what ever you want to use.

For More info visit:
[MonkeyTalk Documentation](http://www.gorillalogic.com/book/monkeytalk-documentation)

Comment: What's the difference between MonkeyRunner and MonkeyTalk?

Comment: Both monkeyrunner and monkeytalk are used for automating android applications and both can run on simulator and devices as well.while with monkeytalk writing scripts is quite easy as it allows the recording feature as well.But with monkey runner no such feature available.Yes Monkey talk is free.

Comment: Does MonkeyRunner support Java? or which language?

Answer (score 0):

At the [Official Selenium Blog](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2013/12/24/android-and-ios-support/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20Selenium%20%28The%20Official%20Selenium%20Blog%29) is stated that selenium is retiring their AndroidDriver and iPhoneDriver in favour of any of:
- [selendroid](http://selendroid.io/)
- [ios-driver](http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/)
- [appium](http://appium.io/)

Answer (score 0):

In Today's date there are 2 tools that are dominating mobile app automated testing:

1. Appium (Open Source)
2. SeeTest (Licensed)

**Why these tools:**

1. Both use underlying iOS instruments and Android sdk, and provide
   various methods to automated your test cases.
2. Both have good support available online
3. Both support same script to be run on both iOS and Android(Crossplatform tesing)
4. Both support multiple languages for coding scripts (C#, Java etc)
5. Both support multiple frameworks - TestNG, JUnit etc

Answer (score -1):

You can use Selenium WebDriver for mobile apps testing. It needs to use "android-server-2.32.0.apk" for Android app testing.
Download link: [Android Driver server apk](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=android-server-2.32.0.apk&can=2&q=)

Please look at this for [AndroidDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver)

Please look at this for [IPhoneDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver)

Comment: Android web driver is used to test how your web application behaves and looks in android web browser.It has nothing to do with an android application.Both are different things.

Comment: So, Isn't it possible to test mobile apps using Android WebDriver?